# Simple CLI Java programme keeps eating up more and more memory

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I've wrote this test programme.

```
import java.io.Console;

public class ConsoleTest{

public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Console console = System.console();
        System.out.println("ConsoleTest initialising... \n Enter command : ");
        String line = "";

        if(console!=null){
            while ( (line = console.readLine())!= null ){
                System.gc();
                System.out.println("your input : " + line);

                if("exit".equalsIgnoreCase(line)){
                    System.out.println("Bye ~");                    
                    System.exit(0);
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Enter command : ");
                }

            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("No console found");
        }


    }
}
```

[image]
I saw heap memory usage constantly going up even while I was writing this question, doing nothing to the programme. 
Also, everytime I click on the Perform GC button, windows taskmanager shows that the programme is using a bit MORE memory.
Is there something wrong with the code ? or is this a normal behaviour ?

**EDIT** 
Later I found that the memory heap usage graph fluctuated regularly on a longer time scale.
 I don't know why it does that but that's another matter I suppose.
If I could ask one more thing, I saw a huge difference between heap usage in Java Monitor and memory usage shown in Windows taskmanager.
Heap usage in Java Monitor showed about 300MB for Eclipse process. 
In Windows taskmanager, 900MB - ish.
Is this difference because the heap usage did not include stack memory usage ?

Answer (score 1):

The amount of memory you're talking about is negligible. The JVM isn't bothering to deal with releasing the small amount. If you want to see more interesting behavior, allocate and then drop references to large blocks before asking for garbage collection.

Comment: granted, that the amount of memory I'm talking about is negligible. However, why does it use up MORE memory ? Even while I wasn't asking the vm to do GC. Of course, whether the VM actually does GC or not is up to the VM thought.

Comment: No way to tell without more details. Perhaps it's taking the opportunity to move items into PermGen and leaving the rest of the heap the same size.

Answer (score 1):

> I saw heap memory usage constantly going up even while I was writing this question, doing nothing to the programme.

It is most likely the monitoring agent that is causing this spontaneous increase in memory usage.  In other words, it is *caused* by your monitoring.

> Also, everytime I click on the Perform GC button, windows taskmanager shows that the programme is using a bit MORE memory.

It is possibly the same issue.  Other possibilities are:

- clicking the GC button is not collecting all heaps, and/or
- the GC is not giving back the reclaimed memory to the operating system.

> Is there something wrong with the code? or is this a normal behaviour?

This is normal behaviour.

The only thing wrong with your code is that it is calling `System.gc()`.  This is a bad idea in most circumstances.